# How can define type of Component in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I define the type of `Component` in a dummy function?

```
@Component({
   templateUrl: 'a'
})
export class MyApp {
}
function dummy(component: any) {
     ....
}       
dummay(MyApp);
```

Comment: Are you trying to pass a class (type) or an instance to `dummy`?

Comment: Yes i am passing  a class : MyApp. I want to remove **any** from dummy function and use correct type

Comment: Have a look at `Class decorators` in https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html

Comment: You use the class name as the type for the argument.  `function dummy(component: MyApp)`

Comment: MyApp can be any class component as it is not usefully.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of different items in your question that could use clarification.

In your example `export class MyApp {...}` is creating a class of type `MyApp`.

Generally you would pass an instance of a class to a function. If that is what you are trying to do, then it would look as follows:

```
function dummy(component: MyApp) {
     ....
}       
dummay(new MyApp());
```

If you are actually trying to pass a class type to the function, then you would want to do the following:

```
import {
  Type
} from '@angular/core';

function dummy(component: Type<any>) {
     ....
}       
dummay(MyApp);
```

Another way you could make this more powerful is if you restricted the components that could be passed to the function to only those that implement a given interface. An example of this would be as follows:

```
import {
  Type
} from '@angular/core';

export interface IFoo {
   id: number;
   getStuff: () => string;
}
@Component({
   templateUrl: 'a'
})
export class MyApp implements IFoo {
}
function dummy(component: Type<IFoo>) {
     const stuff = component.getStuff();
     ....
}    

dummay(MyApp);
```

Comment: Weird that `Type` in this case comes from Angular and not TypeScript?